# How to use regex to grab information from a web page?

Tags: iphone, regex

I'd like to develop an iPhone application that get's it's data from a web pages using regex applied on that web page. I was wondering if that's possible by the SDK.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's a regex you want? Or do you just want to extract a certain piece of text from a web page? In that case, regex probably isn't the best tool for the job.

Comment: There is information laid out in tables and fields and i would like to extract them. Regex is the only thing i could think of, can you suggest something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **NOT** parse HTML using regular expressions.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) if you don't believe me :)

Comment: That link was amazing! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. From my understanding [RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) is widely used and it can be applied as a part of your project or as a static library.